# Difference between Named Equivalence and Structured Equivalence?

Tags: c++

I've been hunting and searching for a way to understand Named Equivalence vs. Structured Equivalence and everything I find has Ada, ALGOL or Pascal examples. I'm more of a C#/Java/C++ developer so their examples aren't getting through to me. I don't know if I'm right, but this is how I think it works:

```
struct One {
  int X;
  double Y;
}

struct Two {
  int J;
  double K;
}

One A = new One();
Two B = new Two();
```

To my (probably flawed) understanding, A and B are NOT of named equivalence, but they are structurally equivalent.

Am I right? Way out of line? Any amount of help would go a long ways. I may need help even wording the question properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spot on with that.
Thats all there is to it actually.

C doesn't have structural equivalence, it supports only name equivalence.
Code like

```
if ( A == B )
```

Will give you an error in languages that don't support structural equivalence.

This isn't much of an answer, you're already on the right track.